# DeadObjectException thrown by queryIntentActivities

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I'm getting the `DeadObjectException` from `queryIntentActivities` rarely.

This is all I found for this issue: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.acra/184 So I tried to adjust my code like following (comment in this code is derived from the post mentioned above).

I'm trying following:

*Old code*

```
List<ResolveInfo> ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
```

*New code*

```
List<ResolveInfo> ril = null;
try
{
    ril = pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
    // process data...
}
catch (DeadObjectException e)
{
    // possibly happens because this process is still running but app is currently being updated by the android system
    // if this is really true, we can ignore the exception as the complete progress will be stopped anyways...
    L.e(e);
}
```

**Problem**

I *can't* catch the exception, because by definition it is never thrown by `queryIntentActivities`. What can I do instead now to avoid this crash? I don't want to catch all exceptions here.

Additionally I'm not sure if this exception really only happens, I've my app is updated while trying to call `queryIntentActivities`, it's just an assumption based on the post above. Can anyone confirm this?

**Stacktrace**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.my.app.receivers.PackageReceiver: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3641)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:765)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:747)
at com.my.app.utils.AppUtil.a(AppUtil.java:230)
at com.my.app.receivers.PackageReceiver.onReceive(PackageReceiver.java:42)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3634)
... 8 more
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:3940)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:755)
... 12 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:765)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:747)
at com.my.app.utils.AppUtil.a(AppUtil.java:230)
at com.my.app.receivers.PackageReceiver.onReceive(PackageReceiver.java:42)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3634)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:3940)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:755)
... 12 more
android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:3940)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:755)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:747)
at com.my.app.utils.AppUtil.a(AppUtil.java:230)
at com.my.app.receivers.PackageReceiver.onReceive(PackageReceiver.java:42)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3634)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Ohh why don't you just remove or comment this line L.e(e); and then try. If exception raised it will not catch and you don't get any error. This is not the standard solution but this really works for me.

Comment: The log is not the problem, I edited my question to show that I just did not catch the exception before. Now I have the problem that I can't use `catch (DeadObjectException e)` but MUST use `catch (Exception e)` instead of it...

Comment: Okey may be it is caused by Hardware problem or the the same thing is used by hardware component this cause the exception. Now for your question you can't catch the exception I don't know what exactly your code is but you can do some trick for that.This is just the suggestion catch you exception with Exception Class now after that convert it to string and then just checked if(yourstring.contains("DeadObjectException")) and do your stuff whatever you want to do in this condition.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, so I can make sure to only catch this single exception and otherwise just throw the exception again. I'll use `if (!(e instanceof DeadObjectException)) throw e;` though

Comment: Yup right. You can try in other device may be in other device it raise the DeadObjectException but its luck may raised or may not so just catch the Exception and do whatever you want to do inside.To catch Exception also helps because if some other exception raised and you just used the DeadObjectException it may chance to crash the app so its better to catch Exception.

Comment: I want the app to crash in other cases, it's better to solve problems than ignoring them. I don't want that I show an empty list of apps in this case... Thanks for the trick, did not think about that myself

Comment: Yup you are right.That's why I said used Exception which catch all the exception so do this trick for DeadObjectException and leave it for the rest of exception if anyother exception occur your app going to crash and found the solution for that.For exception catch you can also used FCM crash reporting which will shows where your app crash in background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147034/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-prom85).